# How to enable sh emulation mode only when using zsh interactively

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh

When using `zsh` interactively, I would like it to emulate the behavior of `sh` as much as possible. I have tried adding `emulate sh` to the end of `~/.zshrc`, but since I am using zsh plugins that rely on `emulate zsh` (e.g. `vcs_info`, [zsh-autosuggestions](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions), and [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting)), I get error messages like these right after running zsh interactively:

```
vcs_info(): expecting numeric arg >= 1 for max-exports (got 2).
Defaulting to 2.
VCS_INFO_set:12: bad math expression: illegal character: {
_zsh_highlight:17: bad set of key/value pairs for associative array
```

The errors above indicate that `emulate sh` is affecting the zsh plugins, which expect zsh emulation. What is the proper way to enable sh emulation mode only for shell commands that are input interactively by the user, while keeping zsh emulation mode for the rest of zsh?

I have added the code below to the end of `~/.zshrc` in an attempt to solve the problem. It seems to work correctly, but I do not know whether or not it is truly correct. I also do not know how/why it works.

```bash
function precmd_emulate_zsh() {
    emulate zsh
}

function preexec_emulate_sh() {
    emulate sh
}

autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook -Uz precmd precmd_emulate_zsh
add-zsh-hook -Uz preexec preexec_emulate_sh
```